# Hide 'add to cart' when certain value in dropdown is selected

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, jquery, dropdown, buttons

Need help here please. I am trying to hide the 'add to cart' woocommerce button when a user selects a specific item in a dropdown list. I have tried multiple JQuery snippets in both functions.php and through 3rd party plugins but am still struggling to get it to work.

**In Functions.php theme file**

```
function load_scripts() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document.getElementsByName("select-1574795073993")).change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="International"){
                    $(".single_add_to_cart_button").hide();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

Please can someone assist with simple steps to 1) provide correct code, and 2) insert in the woocommerce.com hosted plarform.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, there are a few issues here. First off, that's not a proper way to add Javascript to WordPress - [reference The Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/). 2nd, this is a general javascript question which may get more attention on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Thanks very much for the response. I appreciate you sharing the link, however, please can you assist with the wordpress side of things (function, action, file location, etc.) and I will take the JQuery section to StackOverflow. Thnx